# Creating a script component with error in SSIS

Tags: c#, ssis

I am trying to get data from a IT ticketing system through API in SSIS using Script Component, very new to this:

I am just starting with 1 field called Supplier, for that i have so far written below scripts:

[Script Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLBfI.png)

**Created a class called ResultAPI:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SC_b15eeeff0e3544d3a882578b3eb9bbba
{
    public class ResultAPI
    {
       public string Supplier { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**Another class called GenericResponse:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SC_b15eeeff0e3544d3a882578b3eb9bbba
{
    public class GenericResponse

    {
        public ResultAPI[] ListData { get; set; }
    }
    public class ResultGen
    {
        public GenericResponse Result { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Main:**

```
public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
    {

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://***************");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();    
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var cred = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "username", "pwd")));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", cred);
    
            string APIUrl = string.Format("https://**************");

        
            
        
        var response = client.GetAsync(APIUrl).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var data = serializer.Deserialize<ResultAPI>(result);

                APIResultsBuffer.AddRow();
                //APIResultsBuffer.SupplierType = data.SupplierType;
                APIResultsBuffer.Supplier = data.Supplier;
                //APIResultsBuffer.nextpage = data.nextpage;
                //APIResultsBuffer.previouspage = data.previouspage;
                //APIResultsBuffer.recordcount = data.recordcount;
                //APIResultsBuffer.HREF = data.HREF;
            }
        
       

        }
        
    }
```

When I execute the package, i get the attached error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbTOB.png)

Not sure exactly where this error is.

Hoping to download this file in SQL Server table

Comment: `string APIUrl = string.Format("https://**************");` is the line which is causing the error. What are you expecting this line to do? PS, please [include any error messages in your question as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: I removed the url from there, but the same link is working in Power BI and Excel.

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't clear. I understand that the actual URL you're using isn't a load of asterisks, but what do you want to achieve by passing the URL to `string.Format`?

Comment: I actually followed a youtube video and they guy had it this way, so now I have removed it:
One or more errors occurred.
 at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at ScriptMain.CreateNewOutputRows()
   at UserComponent.PrimeOutput(Int32 Outputs, Int32[] OutputIDs, PipelineBuffer[] Buffers, OutputNameMap OutputMap)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.PrimeOutput(Int32 outputs, Int32

Comment: From Execution Results:
[Companies [2]] Error: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)

Comment: OK, sounds like the original problem is resolved and now you have a problem calling the API. "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" suggests to me that the SSL handshake is failing (possibly a problem with certificates). I'd suggest creating a console application or a unit test to make calls to that API, just with the aim of writing some working code to call it but in an environment that's easier to debug than SSIS, and once you've got some working code you can copy it into your script task.

Comment: I got it to work, with adding this line:
      ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

its not a complete dataset yet but i am getting there.

Comment: Now i am stuck with a column that comes in as a List in Power BI for further details, that shows are Records and then when you click further it shows actual values, how do it tackle this?